# How long does windshield washer fluid last in bottles unopened?

Tags: windshield-washer

So I got a bottle of windshield washer fluid almost two years ago and forgot it in the basement. I found it recently and I am wondering if it is still good to use. There is nothing said about expiration time on the bottle.

FYI, the bottle says Windex deicer windshield washer fluid and the color now looks purple, which is not the original color when I bought it, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you bought:

[image]

I'd suggest it should be just fine. As long as it's not opened, there'd be little to no oxidation effects (if that's an effect at all). Even opened, I doubt there's little issue. As long as the liquid is without lumps (which I doubt would occur anyway), there's just about no downside to using it. The only thing which might cause issues is for it to clog your washer system, which, if it runs free/clear, won't be an issue. As you notice, the color is purple like you suggested.

Comment: I agree, washer fluid contains a lot of alcohol, which isn't going to go off.